# How can I grab text before a tag with HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Suppose I have this HTML string:

```
<a href="hello">These are some links</a><br>1234 - <a id="1234" href="#">My Number 1</a><br>4321 - <a href="#">My Number 2</a>...
```

I want to extract the text after the `<br>` tag (1234 -), the inner text of the `<a>` tag (My Number 1), and the `id` attribute of the `<a>` tag (1234) as well. I am using the HTMLAgilityPack to help parse the HTML data that I get.

So far I have tried doing this:

```
        // mNodes = code to get html string I want to parse
        HtmlNode mNumberListNodes = mNodes[1];   // mNodes[1] is equal to a string as shown above
        List<HtmlNode> mNumberNodes = mNumberListNodes.Descendants("a").ToList();
```

I am using debugging points to stop and view the previous child nodes in each of the HtmlNode's, but I am not having any luck finding the corresponding number text.

Anyone have any experience using the HTMLAgilityPack in C# that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the

```
mNodes.InnerText
```

property will give you all the text that is not in html tags, specifically the "1234" you want. Text itself is not a node in the DOM.

Assuming the code above is correct, to get the id value, use:

```
mNumberListNodes.Descendants("a").ToList()[0].Attributes["id"].Value
```

I've had pretty good success using XPath with this library, and also regular expressions.